# Check that we have done() in func call

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

We have a situation, like on in the following code:

```
  if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    return aggregate;
  }

  return aggregate.exec(callback); // returns promise
```

If callback not specified - need to return `aggregate`, and if specified - return promise.

So if we have promise, then we don't have callback and `if (typeof callback === 'undefined')` would be true, but i need false, because we have promise

The problem is that i can't find any information about how i can know whether `.then()` existing or not, can someone point me to the right direction?

**UPDATE**

Explanation:

```
  if (typeof callback === 'undefined') { // need to check that we don't have .then()
    return aggregate; // need to return this only if we don't have promise AND callback
  }

  return aggregate.exec(callback); // returns promise
```

**UPDATE2**

I can't find any information about my situation - i don't think it's duplicate.

The question is - how can we figure out that `.then()` exists **before creating promise**?

Comment: use this -> if (!(typeof callback === 'undefined'))

Comment: i need to return it only in one case: when don't have nor callback, nor promise.

Comment: Can you put some more relevant code. Its a bit difficult to understand what ur usecase is from your description

Comment: see updated answer, i don't know which code could help you understand better

Comment: Test for promise like promiseObj.then && typeof promiseObj.then === 'function'

Comment: Try not to build double-headed APIs. Just *always* return a promise. Less surprises for everyone, easier to code for you.

Comment: need it for backward compatibilty